# Iframe and Jquery AutoComplete Feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete in an html page which is used as source for an ifrmae. 
The height and width of iframe is fixed at around 450px width and 160p px height

Now the issue is when the result set of autocomplete is bit large then the whole setup gets messed up. what I am trying to do is somehow set the z-index of the textboxes so that the result should appear outside of the frame boundary.

Currently I have increased the size of the iframe but thats consuming alot of empty space.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content in an iframe can't "leak" out into it's containing document. You could update the height of the iframe when the autocomplete list is updated.

Check to see how many items are in the list or the height of the list and update the height of the iframe accordingly:

```
$('#some-element').autocomplete({
    change : function (event, ui) {
        var theHeight = $(this).height();
    }
});
```

Comment: That will shift the elements on the page, the other way that I was thinking to get this done is by using getJSON as the file is on a remote server but I am not able to get this working

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you may be making the wrong UI choices if the autocomplete list is too unwieldy.  As Jasper (+1) said the iframe 'leaking' is not going to happen, you can extend your containers using jquery - but you might want to consider using different combinations of controls as well.

For example, could you subdivide your data before the autocomplete box by using an earlier control like a radio list as a filter for the data?   Then when that choice is made adjust the data source of the autocomplete box which could now have a more manageable list in perhaps using something like:

```
var radioValue = $("#radio").val();
$.each(function(key, value) { 
  switch (radioValue)
  {
    case 1: 
    ... filter autocomplete data ... 
    break;
    case 2: ...
  }
});
```